# Throw an exception if a Reactor Flux doesn't complete in a set time

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a potentially long-running Flux that I'd like to stop after a certain duration has passed. I've found several methods of doing this, however what I'm struggling with is how to be able to tell that the Flux timed out rather than just completed naturally.

Sample (very simple) code:

```
Flux.range(0, 10000)
        .take(Duration.ofMillis(1))
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .collectList()
        .block();
```

What I'd like is something like this:

```
Flux.range(0, 10000)
        .take(Duration.ofMillis(1))
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .doOnError(t -> {
            if (t instanceof TimeoutException) {
                System.out.println("I timed out");
            }
        })
        .collectList()
        .block();
```

however `take` doesn't seem to notify on error; all I see is a `terminate` and `complete` signal which is what I get if I don't include the `take` in the Flux and just let it complete naturally.

I've looked briefly into the `timeout` operator which does throw an exception, however `timeout` looks like it'll only throw an exception if the Flux doesn't emit a single element within a certain time, rather than if the whole Flux doesn't complete in a certain time.

Does anyone have any tips or examples of how they've solved this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You can use `takeUntilOther` operator to signal an error after a given time:

```java
Duration timeout = Duration.ofMillis(500);
Flux.range(0, 10000)
    .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(10))
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .takeUntilOther(Mono.delay(timeout).then(Mono.error(new TimeoutException())))
    // .takeUntilOther(Mono.never().timeout(Duration.ofMillis(500))) // based on Michael's answer this is also an option
    .doOnError(t -> {
        if (t instanceof TimeoutException) {
            System.out.println("I timed out");
        }
    })
    .blockLast();
```

---

If `Flux` is converted into `Mono` using for example `.collectList()` or `.then()` operator, then you can simply apply the `.timeout(...)` operator after that and it will behave as you require:

```java
Flux.range(0, 10000)
    .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(10))
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .collectList()
    .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(500))
    .doOnError(t -> {
        if (t instanceof TimeoutException) {
            System.out.println("I timed out");
        }
    })
    .block();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Unfortunately I can't convert my `Flux` to a `Mono` so it seems like Michael's answer is more along the lines of what I'm looking for :)

Comment: @helencrump Makes sense. I see Michael's answer didn't work out for you so I updated mine with an alternative which seems to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Ah great, the `takeUntilOther` has done what I wanted - thanks a lot Martin!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `take()`, you can use `.mergeWith(Flux.never().timeout(Duration.ofMillis(500)))` to merge your flux with another that will always throw a timeout exception after a certain timeframe.

To take your example, you'd do something like:

```
Flux.range(0, 10000)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(10))
        .mergeWith(Flux.<Integer>never().timeout(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .doOnError(t -> {
            if (t instanceof TimeoutException) {
                System.out.println("I timed out");
            }
        })
        .collectList()
        .block();
```

...which will give you something like:

```
(...snip)
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
I timed out
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a nice solution. However, if I'm reading the documentation for `Flux.never()` correctly, it looks like it'll never signal completion, and from testing in my own code it seems like my Flux will never complete until the `Flux.never()` times out, which unfortunately isn't what I'm looking for, unless I've misunderstood something.

Comment: It feels like I'd want to signal completion of the `Flux.never()` (or equivalent) when my `Flux` completes, however I'm not sure if that's doable.